# What is the output format of a webcam?

Tags: hardware, webcam, microcontroller

What is the output format of a webcam? I want to create a microcontroller device which can capture a frame from a USB webcam and I need to know what format the output from the webcam is in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the webcam, it can be in RGB, BGR, YUV and various others, even JPEG. You might be better looking for a CCD module that you can interface to your micro rather then a USB solution as you will need to engineer a compatible USB driver as there is no standard for webcams like there is for storage devices (mass storage device).

Something like this: http://www.jrobot.net/Projects/AVRcam.html

Or probably even better: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8668 (i2c for control, 8bit parallel for data and supports RGB, YUV and JPEG compressed formats)

Comment: There is a standard - the USB Video Class (see http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs which shows no less than 7 payload formats) - but as you say, there are a lot of different formats, any of which may or may not be supported by a device. Some even support different formats depending on other parameters, like resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the camera, really. But most sensors output in YUV (or YCbCr) and it's variants